# Git sync with local folder - sync like

Tags: git, repository, synchronization, local

There is this main git repository "MainRepo"

And here comes the new repository "NewRepo"

Newrepo uses the exact files/folder content/structure of "MainRepo" folder, except git folder.

So its basically , copy contents to a new folder , "git it" and push it to a new remote repository.

Now it loses connection with "NewRepo" .

However , i want to continue working on NewRepo but also keep in sync with the OldRepo.

Every now and then , some files change in OldRepo and i want to reflect those small changes to NewRepo.

My idea was to add a new remote to NewRepo , targetting either the OldRepo url or the OldRepo's local repository folder path.

And wish a merge and Boom !

All of the files show as Conflict , not just the 3 files that have changed.

Is this kind of merge even possible ? I would imagine this to be named "cross repo merge".

Or does this action go into the territory of syncing folders ? And not git merging.

Help me , i love git so much , sometimes my love increases my expectations too much and end up in this path with nowhere to go.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that OldRepo has history that NewRepo does not share, and therefore they are seen as completely different repos even though they have the same file content. If you create the NewRepo by cloning OldRepo, this should be solved.

Sounds like this is what you want.

Comment: If it wasn't an independent project / something like fork with no history tree or dependency, i would do that . 
However this NewRepo should not have any dependency on other repositories. Just some ninja sync from time to time.

Comment: I still think the history part is the problem, different history means they are seen as completely different repositories, and no easy merge. you could probably use fetch, and then do a merge of the specific files that has changed.
Is there a specific reason you do not want to have any dependencies to another repo?

Comment: No specific reason at all. This is just a clone of a project, which needs to grow by itself and head its own direction, being managed by a different team . But at first , new team does not develop anything new and the first project is being updated frequently.
Dont want to mix two teams inside one repository, it is possible however. But eventually , i would like git to do its magic and work this out :) , its true , history trees etc, Gitwise this is a nightmare , but you know only so much , so i asked , maybe...

Comment: Unwillingly i did merge from OldRepo , there are still no connections . And resolved conflicts by using all of the OldRepo's files. My expectation is , from this point on, the files will at least have somewhat similar history tree and i will be able to merge further updates from OldRepo into NewRepo , by defining a new remote.

Answer (score 0):

#### I have a similar situation, and I use `rsync`:

I'm fine using any tool that works, but an *all-*`git` solution seems like overkill to me -- or perhaps I'm just more *comfortable* with `rsync` than `git`. Anyway - here comes `new repository "NewRepo" w/ exact files/folder content/structure of "MainRepo" folder, except git folder.`

##### Update "MainRepo" to match desired components of "NewRepo":

Use `rsync` format:

> rsync [options] Source Destination:

Used this way, `rsync` brings the **Destination** folder into sync with the **Source** folder. Important details are shown in the following example:

```bash
$ rsync -rptgovic --dry-run --delete --exclude=filepattern1 --exclude=filepattern2 NewRepo MainRepo
```

`NewRepo` and `MainRepo` are expressed as folder specifications; e.g. `/home/$USER/somefoldername`, or `./somefoldername` depending on your `pwd`.

The `options` consist of the string `ptgovidcC`, and other instructions to `rsync`

Note *in particular* the `i` option in `ptgovidcC`, and the `--dry-run` option. These options, used together, allow you "practice runs" to make sure your `rsync` command options are doing what you need.

The `--exclude=` option may be repeated as many times as necessary to keep unwanted files/folders out of `MainRepo`

In the above command, `NewRepo` is the **Source**, and `MainRepo` is the **Destination**

Of course you should ***always*** consult `man rsync` to ensure your command is appropriate for your objectives.

##### Update "NewRepo" to match "MainRepo":

This is basically the same drill as above, but now `MainRepo` is the **Source**, and `NewRepo` is the **Destination**

The `options` will obviously need to change also, but once again, the `i` and `--dry-run` options serve as your *"proving ground"*.

##### Interpreting the `i` output:

This isn't as hard as it's going to look seeing it for the first time, but this "map" will allow you to interpret `rsync` actions taken - or ***to be taken*** when using `--dry-run`:

```
Understanding the output of rsync --itemize-changes

As you may know the rsync's --delete options if misused could make severe damage.

To prevent this you can use the --itemize-change and the --dry-run options to figure out how the command will behave before launching the real one.

The output will be something like that:

.d..t..g... ./
.f...p.g... Something.pdf
.f.....g... md5sum-2010-02-21.txt
.f...p.g... prova.rb
.d.....g... .metadata/
.f...p.g... .metadata/.lock
.f...p.g... .metadata/.log
.f...p.g... .metadata/version.ini
>f+++++++++ Parameter_Usage.txt

Where the first field of each line tell what rsync would do to each file.

I wrote this little schema that helped me to understand this output format and I'm publishing hoping it will be useful for others.

YXcstpoguax  path/to/file
|||||||||||
`----------- the type of update being done::
 ||||||||||   <: file is being transferred to the remote host (sent).
 ||||||||||   >: file is being transferred to the local host (received).
 ||||||||||   c: local change/creation for the item, such as:
 ||||||||||      - the creation of a directory
 ||||||||||      - the changing of a symlink,
 ||||||||||      - etc.
 ||||||||||   h: the item is a hard link to another item (requires --hard-links).
 ||||||||||   .: the item is not being updated (though it might have attributes that are being modified).
 ||||||||||   *: means that the rest of the itemized-output area contains a message (e.g. "deleting").
 ||||||||||
 `---------- the file type:
  |||||||||   f for a file,
  |||||||||   d for a directory,
  |||||||||   L for a symlink,
  |||||||||   D for a device,
  |||||||||   S for a special file (e.g. named sockets and fifos).
  |||||||||
  `--------- c: different checksum (for regular files)
   ||||||||     changed value (for symlink, device, and special file)
   `-------- s: Size is different
    `------- t: Modification time is different
     `------ p: Permission are different
      `----- o: Owner is different
       `---- g: Group is different
        `--- u: The u slot is reserved for future use.
         `-- a: The ACL information changed
```

This schema is based on the contents of the `-i, --itemize-changes` option in `man rsync`, organized to facilitate easier reference<sup>[REF](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=Understanding+the+output+of+rsync+--itemize-changes)</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can use robocopy to 'sync' changes from an untracked folder into a git branch folder.

`robocopy <Source Folder> <Destination Git Folder> /MIR /MT:8 /R:1 /W:1 /XD ".git" /XF ".gitignore" /l`

Remove the `/l` parameter when you are happy the right files are being copied and deleted in the destination. (`/l` lists operations but does not perform them.)

Then use git commands or git gui to stage and commit the desired changes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy